# Error with TCL while testing a python code

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tcl

I'm trying to test a code in python (from internet)

```
from numpy import corrcoef, sum, log, arange
from numpy.random import rand
from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks

# generating some uncorrelated data
data = rand(10,100) # each row of represents a variable

# creating correlation between the variables
# variable 2 is correlated with all the other variables
data[2,:] = sum(data,0)
# variable 4 is correlated with variable 8
data[4,:] = log(data[8,:])*0.5

# plotting the correlation matrix
R = corrcoef(data)
pcolor(R)
colorbar()
yticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
xticks(arange(0.5,10.5),range(0,10))
show()
```

but when I execute this script an error message appear

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    pcolor(R)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2921, in pcolor
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 803, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 450, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 423, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 79, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 87, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/local/lib/tcl8.6 /usr/lib/tcl8.6 /lib/tcl8.6 /usr/library /library /tcl8.6.4/library /tcl8.6.4/library

/usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.4, need exactly 8.6.1
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.4, need exactly 8.6.1
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.6.1"
    (file "/usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source /usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I tried to reinstall tcl, but I cant install the specific version, can anyone help me please with any idea??

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I think you should add also linux and ubuntu tag to your question

Comment: I will do that, thanks Harun

Comment: Are you setting the `TCL_LIBRARY` environment variable? Can you try _not_ doing that?

Comment: @DonalFellows I'm not setting the TCL_LIBRARY

Comment: Well, from a Tcl perspective what's going on is that the library and the supporting script files it is trying to initialise with are from slightly different versions. This seems to be a relatively common problem with how Tcl is used when embedded inside Python (as part of Tkinter) so I'm guessing that there's a misconfiguration in there. Note that I'm not saying _you_ have done anything wrong, just that it's ended up being wrong somehow.

Comment: @DonalFellows  I test the code in my laptop and it's work perfectly, so the problem is in my desktop, any idea about how can i fix this missconfiguration?